# Java security policy file question

Tags: java, windows-7, configuration-files, system-administration

Okay guys, I am trying to get the interpreter to use my .policy file for some JAAS stuff I am doing.  When I try to enter the extra entry **(ie. policy.url.3=file:/C:/Test/raypolicy
)**  in my **Windows:java.home\lib\security\java.security** 
file, it refuses to save the new entry.  I get a ***Save not successuful*** prompt telling me to make sure that the program is not open in somewhere else. Of course, it is not open somewhere else.

I know that it is a wrong setting somewhere on my computer as I am able to save to my java security file on my computer at work.  I am running a Windows 7 on my personal computer and a windows xp at work. I have also already checked the file settings for the security file and I am set up as the administrator so I have authority to change the file, etc.  Any and all thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Are you sure it's not open somewhere else? How do you know?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you run the editor you use to edit the file (e.g. notepad) as Administrator -- otherwise the file permissions set on that directory will not allow you to modify the file.
Right click on notepad, select "Run as administrator" then load the file in notepad, edit it and save it and that should work.

Comment: That sounds like it should do the trick. . . I can't use my laptop for another hour when I take my next break. . . but I will let you know what happens.  Thanks Liv!!!

Comment: Sorry about that Liv! I thought I accepted that answer on May 16. . . my apologies.  Thanks again for your help:)

Answer (score 1):

One more option that worked for me was,

1. Copied the original file `java.security` to my desktop.
2. Changed the desktop version using notepad++ or any editor
3. Saved it.
4. And copied back this updated version to original file replacing the entire file.
5. Opened the file to confirm the changes
6. Deleted the desktop version.